# DataTable Export Data -> Customized HTML stripping

Tags: javascript, regex, datatable, export

I'm trying to export some data from my datatables with formatted HTML tags.
My goal is to extract all visible text (innerhtml) and also the tooltip text from a separate data field (`data-original-title="xxx"`).

For example some datatable rows:

```html
<td><span class="text-success"><abbr data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" data-original-title="XX: 2.55 (0.00|5.00) <br>YY: -10.15 (-27.96|-9.00)">xx/yy</abbr></span></td>
<td><span class="text-success"><abbr data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" data-original-title="<b>section 1</b>: 0, <b>section 2</b>: 0, <b>section 3</b>: 2, <b>section 4</b>: 5, <b>section 5</b>: 1">8</abbr></span></td>
```

I want something like this:

```
XX: 2.55 (0.00|5.00) <br>YY: -10.15 (-27.96|-9.00) - xx/yy
section 1: 0, section 2: 0, section 3: 2, section 4: 5, section 5: 1 - 8
```

The default behaviour is good, but builds this (problem: `">`):

```
XX: 2.55 (0.00|5.00) <br>YY: -10.15 (-27.96|-9.00)">xx/yy
section 1: 0, section 2: 0, section 3: 2, section 4: 5, section 5: 1">8
```

Is there a way to use an additional replace after the onboard HTML strip from datatable?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use some JS to access the data attribute and the text content of the DOM element? this would be safer than trying to use a regular expression to do that. Or is it because you have to do some server-side logic? if it's the case, what techno are you using server-side?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The export happens on client side. You have a good point. I think I'm going to try this. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone got the same question, this is my solution.
I couldn't take the 'data attribute' answer because my row data often had several html levels.

This is my result:

```
format:  {
    // Manipulation der Export Daten
    body: (data, row, column, node) => {
        // Extract tooltip, if available
        const tooltipExtract = (data) => {
            const regex = /(data-original-title=").*?(">)/g
            if (regex.test(data)) {
                const tooltipExtraced = data.match(regex) // Matched Tooltip with html in innertext
                return tooltipExtraced[0].replace(/<[^>"']*((("[^"]*")|('[^']*'))[^"'>]*)*>|(data-original-title=")|">/g, '').trim() // Deletes html tags and the beginning/ending of the tooltip
            }
            return false
        }

        // Extract data
        const innerData = data.replace(/<[^>"']*((("[^"]*")|('[^']*'))[^"'>]*)*>/g, '').trim() // Innertext
        const tooltip = tooltipExtract(data)    // Tooltip

        // Result with or without Tooltip
        if (tooltip) {
            return `${innerData} -> ${tooltip}`
        }
        return innerData
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
var buttonCommon = {
        exportOptions: {
            format: {
                body: function ( data, row, column, node ) {

                    title = $(row).data('original-title');
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is what I'm looking for. But `row` is only the row index.